# Verify your internet connection Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

when i run the app i get an error:

> “Verify Internet Connection”

Meanwhile my laptop and my mobile device has got internet what could be the problem?

Comment: There maybe problems like, Wifi is not connected to internet. Forget the network and reconnect

Comment: this appears on the mobile device , immediately the message pops up the app loads till infinity

Comment: if you are using data_connection_checker, this may be the problem. This plugin doesnt work in all countries

Comment: Do you use an emulator or physical device?

Comment: Please add all the details about this. We can't see what you're doing and you're just making people guessing. What are you running? Did it work earlier? What caused it not to work anymore? etc.

Comment: @hisam i use physical device

Comment: @JamesZ what do you want to see

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happen. Have you try add internet permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` located at `android/app/src/main` you need to add tag :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: yeah it has been added but could not help me